# Как правильно прописать переменные в атрибутах jade php?

Tags: jade, php

Здравствуйте.

Как правильно прописать переменные в атрибутах jade php?

К примеру, в элементе прописать переменную так:

```
a= $text
```

а в атрибуте

```
a(href=$link)= $text
```

Второй вариант не работает, как верно его прописать?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
a(href=$link) $text
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, решил переходом на более древнюю версию jade php